# Can not access converted xml to json

Tags: node.js, json, xml

I got a problem while working on a project, that involves converting a .xml file to json. I am using the package xml2js to do this. When I console log the json that has been stringified I get normal looking json. But I can not access any objects in there by typing json.station as an example. Up my code I tried it by using json I wrote and there I do not have this problem. The converted json and my own is looking identical to me.

```
const xml = '<timetable station="Berlin S&#252;dkreuz" eva="8011113"><s id="-6544008849917647305-2112082040-19" eva="8011113"><ar ct="2112082232" l="5"/><dp ct="2112082234" l="5"/></s> </timetable>';

const data = {
    "timetable": {
        "$": {
            "station": "Test"
        }
    }
}

console.log(data.timetable.$.station + '\n')

xml2js_parser(xml, function (err, result) {
    const json = JSON.stringify(result, null, 4)
    console.log(json.timetable)
});
```

Comment: When you use `JSON.strinify()` you are  converting the object into a string, and that string won't have any of the JSON properties accessible. Don't stringify it, or grab the `result.timetable` before you do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse it back to JSON, why do you stringify it?

```js
xml2js_parser(xml, function (err, result) {
    const json = JSON.stringify(result, null, 4)
    console.log(JSON.parse(json).timetable)
});
```